# Do we have a default message template for new users that indicates how they can improve their post?

Tags: discussion, comments, new-users

I find myself sometimes in the situation where I would like to comment on a new user's answer, how the site works and why their answer is downvoted. Do we have a default template for that or does somebody have a custom text they could recommend?

**Edit:** With the respect to the apparent duplicate, let me clarify, that this is not a default welcoming that I want to paste for every new user. The intent was rather to have a response to give to new users who clearly struggle to understand how this site works. For example, answering a question in a bulletin-board style (raising other questions or providing (amusing) anecdote that doesn't answer the question).

I think this is substantially different from the question [How should we reach out to new users?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1384/how-should-we-reach-out-to-new-users?lq=1) and should be reflected in the answers.

Comment: Is this just for your personal use, or are you looking for something that the site could use as a whole (by choice, of course)?

Comment: @Slytherincess: Why does it have to be either/or? I was first and foremost looking for a template I can copy/paste when appropriate, but that could be used by more people than just myself.

Comment: @Mooz: I tried to clarify what I wanted with this question. I think it is different from the one you link to.

Comment: @bitmask -- It doesn't *have* to be either. I was just asking for clarification.

Comment: FWIW, such a templated message would be useful to add to a customized build of the [Auto Review Comments](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) Userscript.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SciFi.StackExchange. This site does not work like a regular bulletin board. We prefer answers that are well sourced and address the original question where they were posted.

[This post is work-in-progress, feel free to extend it]